# How to limit the number of list elements when displaying the tags for a post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I get the all tags for my post type, and they are all being displayed. I need to limit this to show only five. Since I do not work with php, I need help on how to implement this correctly. I tried using `array_slice` method but I got an error.

```
<div class="menu_grid__tags">
    <?php $tags = get_all_tags_from_post_type( "news" );
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {?>
<?php print $tag ?>
        <a class="menu_grid__tag" href="<?= get_category_link( $tag ) ?>"><?=  $tag->name ?></a>
    <?php }; ?>
</div>
```

And the `get_all_tags_from_post_type` function is:

```
function get_all_tags_from_post_type( $type ) { 
    $type_ids = get_post_type_ids( $type ); 
    return wp_get_object_terms( $type_ids, 'post_tag' ); 
}
```

Comment: What is the `get_all_tags_from_post_type` function? It would be *much more efficient* to limit the elements there, if its your own custom function.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to loop five elements, instead of all elements, use a [**`for()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, and not a [**`foreach()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Change `foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {...}` to...

```
for($i = 0; $i < min(5, count($tags)); $i++) {
    $tag = $tags[$i];
    // (the rest of the code you have
}
```

Then it will only go over 5 tags, or, if there are fewer than 5 tags, just that many, because we are using `min(5, count($tags))`.

Comment: Solution didn't help

Comment: Hi, Aleksf: Can you give an explanation that would be helpful?  I can't really help "didn't work" answers.  What was the error?  What happened?

Comment: Hello. What specific explanation are you interested in? About my attempts with the array_slice method? Rather, everything is not the correct implementation, but it is not as unrelated to the question

Comment: I have not received any errors, the list is displayed in full

Comment: Aleksf: In that case, I recommend putting `print('test');`, because you're probably not updating your code correctly.  The documentation links I provided above clearly explain what `for(....$i < 5...)` does, although just looking at it somewhat looks trivially intuitive, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `get_all_tags_from_post_type` function to return only the number of objects you want - this is more efficient than getting all WP_Term objects and then processing the list then to limit the number.

You just need these few changes:

1. **Add a parameter to specify how many tags to get** to the `get_all_tags_from_post_type` function. We also give it a default of 9999 so it will return all if no value is passed in
2. **Limit the list to only include that number of tags**, if a value was passed in.
3. **That's it**! Step 2 means we only get the Term objects for the ids in our new limited list, and returns just those

```
/* 1. Add a parameter to the function to specify how many tags to get
   Default value = 9999 so it will get all if no values is passed in */
function get_all_tags_from_post_type( $type, $numberOfTags=9999) { 
    $type_ids = get_post_type_ids( $type ); 

    /* 2. if numberOfTags was passed in, limit the list to only include that number of elements */
    if ($numberOfTags < 9999)
        $type_ids= array_slice($type_ids, 0, $numberOfTags, true);

    /* 3. Now only return the Term objects for those ids */
    return wp_get_object_terms( $type_ids, 'post_tag' ); 
}
```

Using this version of your function, you just need to tell it how many elements you want to get, e.g. **to get 5 elements change this**:

```
$tags = get_all_tags_from_post_type( "news" );
```

**...to this:**

```
$tags = get_all_tags_from_post_type( "news", 5 );
```

Comment: @Aleksf This answer should work for you it assumes `get_post_type_ids` will always return an array, but without knowing how that function works you might need to first check that it is before calling `array_slice`. Can you show us the `get_post_type_ids` function - depending on how it works, it might even be better to do it there.